# How to diagnose configuration---:w doesn't always work

Tags: vimrc, save

I've somehow introduced a problem in my Vim configuration and I don't know how to track down where the problem is. Sometimes (most times) when I do `:w` then the buffer is not actually written; something else happens instead.

**What can I do to find out what is happening so I know what to fix?**

Comment: Is your vim config under source/version control? Do you have any other ideas what happens when you `:write` ? Have you tried `vim --clean`?

Comment: For now your question is an exact duplicate of [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) so I'll close it as a duplicate. You should follow what the answer to the question says and once you find the problem if you don't know how to solve it you can ask another question with the details of what isn't working. Also if you end up asking another question, please be more specific than "something else happens instead" because it is almost impossible for other users to debug an issue like this.